# LINQ query returns 'This method supports the LINQ to Entities infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.' exception

Tags: c#, .net, linq

On this query specifically:

```cs
var filteredPersonApplications = (from pa in personApplicationsId
    join pa2 in manualPersonApplications on new { ApplicationId = applicationId, PersonId = pa } equals new { pa2.ApplicationId, pa2.PersonId } into papa2
    from pa2 in papa2.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join pa3 in automaticPersonApplications on new { ApplicationId = applicationId, PersonId = pa } equals new { pa3.ApplicationId, pa3.PersonId } into papa3
    from pa3 in papa3.DefaultIfEmpty()
    orderby pa
    select new
    {
        PersonId = pa,
        ManualPersonApplication = pa2,
        AutomaticPersonApplication = pa3,
        ManualPerson = pa2.Person, // Just to include in query
        AutomaticPerson = pa3.Person // Just to include in query
    }).ToList();
```

I'm not sure what to make of this error, or how to begin solving it. It's my first time encountering this.. Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: What the source of your collections?